# why cant i close this program?

Tags: java, swing

i have an program which is an JFrame, but when i use my "starting" action it isn't able to be switched of, instead it just sticks running and I need to force-close it :( could you say me why, because I'm new to coding an i dont find my mistake here is my code:

```
public class ClickBotSetUp extends JFrame  {

    static ClickBotSetUp frame;
    static Robot robot;

    public static void ClickBot() throws AWTException{
        final Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.delay(2000);

        while(true)
        {
            {
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                robot.delay(least);   
            }
        }
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {

        frame = new ClickBotSetUp("setup speed");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        robot = new Robot();
    }

//settings
static int least = 100;
JTextField count;
JButton start;
static int bot = 0;

public ClickBotSetUp(String title) throws HeadlessException
{
    super(title);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(180, 145);

    Container cont = getContentPane();
    cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ((JComponent) cont).setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15,
            15, 15));

    //desing

    JLabel instructions = new JLabel("low nubers can crash");
    cont.add(instructions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //buttons

    start = new JButton("start");
    start.setAction(starting);
    cont.add(start, BorderLayout.WEST);

    //score 

    JPanel scores = new JPanel();
    scores.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cont.add(scores, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel times = new JPanel();
    times.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    scores.add(times, BorderLayout.WEST);

    //times

    count = new JTextField("100");
    count.setEditable(false);
    times.add(count, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton add10 = new JButton("+10");
    add10.setAction(add_10);
    times.add(add10, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JButton remove10 = new JButton("-10");
    remove10.setAction(remove_10);
    times.add(remove10, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private AbstractAction starting = new AbstractAction("start") {

       @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          frame.setVisible(false);

          try {
            ClickBot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }
};

private AbstractAction add_10 = new AbstractAction("+10") {

       @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        least = least + 10;
           count.setText("" +least+ "");
       }
};

private AbstractAction remove_10 = new AbstractAction("-10") {

       @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

           if(least < 20){
           }else{
           least = least - 10;
           count.setText("" +least+ "");
           }

       }
};
}
```

Comment: <code>while(true)</code> will create a never ending loop. you should be using a flag and when a condition is met that flag should be changed so that the loop may be exited.

Answer (score 5):

`while(true`) is an infinite loop. It will never exit this.

Have some condition in the while(someCondition Here) which will break the while loop.

Also as @ArnaudDenoyelle pointed out

You need the line

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

That is because the default behavior for the JFrame for the X button is the equivalent to

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

So most of the times you will need to add the line manually when creating your JFrame

Comment: (I downvoted) Sorry but when the user clicks the close the frame, the program must stop. The problem actually comes from `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. imho, `while(true)` is correct for a robot.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The EXIT_ON_CLOSE generally works, but yes it is definitely a bad practice. Also there was this infinite loop condition because of which the OP had to force close it. That is the reason I believed while(true) is a big reason for the same. General causes for a force close is when a program hangs or gets stuck in an infinite loop, and do not bother for downvote. That's fine.

Answer (score 2):

`while(true)` will create a never ending loop. you should be using a flag and when a condition is met that flag should be changed so that the loop may be exited.